# Как записать значение чекбокса(tkinter) в sqlite базу данных?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3

```py
var1 = IntVar()

c1 = Checkbutton(text="First", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

c1.pack(anchor=W)

var2 = IntVar()

c2 = Checkbutton(text="Second", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

c2.pack(anchor=W)


conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

conn.execute("INSERT INTO TestDB VALUES (:var1, :var2)", {'var1': var1.get(), 'var2': var2.get()})

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Comment: В базу данных при запуске пишутся нули,подскажите,что не так,ибо на зарубежном аналоге сказали,что значения снимаются задолго до того,как пользователь увидит сам UI

Comment: Правильно вам сказали, у вас значения снимаются сразу при создании окна, пользователь физически не может успеть ничего изменить. Поэтому и нужно сохранение данных вешать на обработчик нажатия кнопки или какого-то события (пользователь что-то поменял, нажал кнопку - данные сохранились).

Answer (score 0):

Странно,но решил сделать функцию,которая будет снимать значение и все заработало

```py
root = Tk()
root.title("getcheck")
root.geometry("350x250")

def create_DB():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestDB (var1 integer, var2 integer)""")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def get_var():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO TestDB VALUES (:var1, :var2)", {'var1': var1.get(), 'var2': var2.get()})
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



btn = Button(root, text = "Создаем бд", command = create_DB).pack(anchor = W)
btn1 = Button(root, text = "Снимаем значение", command = get_var).pack(anchor = W)


var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text = "Первое значение", variable = var1).place(x = 75,y = 1)

var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text = "Второе значение", variable = var2).place(x = 120, y = 28)

root.mainloop()
```